# best design pattern for handling multiple incoming and outgoing connections

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a scenario where I am dealing with multiple incoming and outgoing connections. Which design pattern in java will be suitable for me to deal with such scenario.

I have multiple incoming connections like FTP, SFTP , HTTP , Database and multiple outgoing connections also FTP , SFTP , HTTP , Database. I am new to design patterns , I just want to know which design pattern best fit in my case.

Comment: This question is too broad. Try to elaborate and show difficulties with the current design.

Comment: *I just want to know which design pattern best fit in my case.*, the one that you decide best fits your case after you study all of them

Comment: A framework such as netty.io uses lots of patterns, including the one Akira mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend the Half-Sync Half-Async (http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/PLoP-95.pdf) as a general way to deal with the complexity of having (possibly) blocking communication creating asynchronous tasks that need to be executed in order to give a result back to the caller.

It is a very general design pattern so it certainly fits several client-servers protocols you cited.

ESB, suggested in another answer is not adequate to what you are looking for, since it is based on a model in which you have several processes all connected to a message bus. All those processes exchange messages and they are all typically connected to one or more message queues or message topics. Think of it as the postal service. All houses (processes) have the same role and all of them talk with the postal service in order to exchange messages.

In your problem, you have two distinct roles: a client role and a server role. Your problem seems to be how to organize the server internally, not how to coordinate servers or equal peers.